# jQuery to load hidden divs as content sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, onclick, show-hide

I have a jQuery driven side navigation menu that on click of a li loads a hidden div. When I click another li I just have a hide() function on every every other hidden div id.  Ideally I am looking for a way to when I click a li, it shows the hidden div and hides the div that was there previously.  I have to load each hidden div based on id, but I figure there is some way to hide the current content before I load the new div.  Here is how I currently have it:

```
         <ul>
            <li id="overview" class="selector"><a href="#">OVERVIEW</a></li>
            <li id="whyus" class="selector"><a href="#">WHY US</a></li>
            <li id="clients" class="selector"><a href="#">CLIENTS & TESTIMONIALS</a>   </li>
            <li id="staff" class="selector"><a href="#">MEET THE STAFF</a></li>
        </ul>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#overviewHidden").fadeIn();
    jQuery("li#overview").addClass('active');



jQuery("li.selector").click(function () {
  jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  jQuery(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});



    jQuery("#overview").click(function(){
        jQuery('#whyusHidden, #clientsHidden, #staffHidden').hide();
                    jQuery('#overviewHidden').slideDown();
    });

    jQuery("#whyus").click(function(){
        jQuery('#overviewHidden, #clientsHidden, #staffHidden').hide();
                    jQuery('#whyusHidden').slideDown();
    });

    jQuery("#clients").click(function(){
        jQuery('#overviewHidden, #whyusHidden, #staffHidden').hide();
                    jQuery('#clientsHidden').slideDown();   
    });

    jQuery("#staff").click(function(){
        jQuery('#clientsHidden, #overviewHidden, #whyusHidden').hide();
                    jQuery('#staffHidden').slideDown();
    });
```

});

Instead of a hide() on all the div's , I would like to hide whatever the current div is.  Thanks,

Comment: Can you share the html for the hidden div's

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add a class to all hidden div's like `hidden-container` then in your click handler use it to hide the elements instead of using hard coded ids.

Ex

```
jQuery("#whyus").click(function(){
    var hidden = jQuery('#whyusHidden');
    jQuery('.hidden-container').not(hidden).hide();
    hidden.slideDown();
});
```

Also you can improve the solution by removing the individual click handlers

For this you need to add a class called `hidden-container` to each of these divs

```
jQuery("li.selector").click(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.addClass('active');
    $this.siblings().removeClass('active');

    var hidden = jQuery('#' + this.id + 'Hidden');
    jQuery('.hidden-container').not(hidden).hide();
    hidden.slideDown();
});
```

because from what I can see the `id` of the hidden id is nothing but the clicked li's `id` + `Hidden`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J7wyA/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply toggle the active class name on or off when clicking your links, and hide the active div at the same time. Here is a working example http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/eFdjI

You can also improve your code by adding a class to the `ul` instead of each `li`. Then use individual class names on each `li` to select the hidden divs. You dont need to use `<a>` tags as you can assign a click function to the `<li>` tags just as easily.

```
$('.selector li').click(function(){
  //hide current displayed div
  $('.active').toggleClass('active').hide();

  //get the class name of this item to select the hidden div.
  var theId = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
  //show the div, assign active class
    $(theId).toggleClass('active').fadeIn(500);
});
```

hope this helps